# How to format LocalTime with time-of-day abbreviation depending on device locale?

Tags: kotlin, java-8, localtime, time-format

What's the best way to show a `LocalTime` value based on the device? The United States is the only nation that exclusively uses the AM/PM time of day abbreviation but for some reason the abbreviation does not appear whenever my device locale is set to the United States.

**United States**

2:30 AM / 2:30 PM

**Elsewhere around the world**

02:30 / 14:30

**Current code**

myTV.text = LocalTime.of(2, 30) + " " + LocalTime.of(14, 30)

**Current result**

2:30 14:30

Comment: @OleV.V. This answer only shows if I want to use AM/PM all the time, which I don’t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to format your times explicitly. Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter localizedTimeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT);
    LocalTime begin = LocalTime.of(2, 30);
    LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(14, 30);

    String text = begin.format(localizedTimeFormatter) + ' ' + end.format(localizedTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(text);
```

Sorry that I can write only Java code. When I ran the code on my desktop Java 9 with default locale set to US, the output was:

> 2:30 AM 2:30 PM

Output with other locales:

- Canada: `2:30 AM 2:30 PM`
- UK or France: `02:30 14:30`